# What are these hanging lamps used in Alien: Convenant?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

In *Alien: Covenant*, hanging lamps start to glow when David approaches them.

[image]

What are they, anyway?

Comment: Are you asking in universe or what out of universe prop was used.

Comment: They aren't mentioned in the books, other than as "lights"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-universe, the props looks like off-the-shelf Himalayan salt lamps.  [Here is a tabletop version](https://himalayantradingco.com/products/original-himalayan-salt-lamp-medium?variant=19609209372758), although wall-mounted and hanging ones like those shown exist as well.  They have a standard light fitting inside a thing layer of translucent pink-orange salt.  (There are other kinds of similar stone-lined lamps, but the salt ones are the most common and the most robust—since other kinds of stone are less translucent than salt, meaning the outer layers have to be thinner and thus more fragile.)

The one in the link and the ones shown in the scene are not completely standardized in shape and are typically sold based just on size and rough overall shape, and is clear that multiple sizes were used to light the set.  The variable sizes, and especially the rough, mineral surfaces of the lamp exteriors do a good job of complementing the "rustic" feel of that building.

Answer (score 2):

[Brendan Seals](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm3567168/), VFX Supervisor for Luma Pictures, the visual effects company responsible for these lights in *Alien: Covenant*, and the person responsible for creating these lamps [explained Luma’s approach for the lamps](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.artofvfx.com/alien-covenant-brendan-seals-vfx-supervisor-luma-pictures/amp/):

> **Inside David’s place there are floating lights. Can you explain in detail about their creation?** 
> The lights are the primary light source of the laboratory. The Director of Photography, David Wolski, set a really interesting mood and lit the set with suspended lanterns, so we had a lot to work with in respect to what was captured on camera. The elliptical lamps that we created were very much inspired by crystal salt lamps.
> We initially designed a lamp made of caul fat membrane with a sheath wrapped around the lights. As we went on, we realised the lamps were calling too much attention to themselves, which detracted from the intensity of the dialogue. So we refrained from this initial concept and took some of the vein elements of the sheath and used that as an additional layer on top of the practical photography. As far as the lights themselves, we simulated orbs that move inside the lamp along with a swarm of motes that move around the light source.
> [image]

[Luma Pictures details a little bit about the lamps on their own website.](https://www.luma.inc/pictures/projects/alien-covenant)

The lamps are inspired by salt lamps, but are not; they were created by Luma, trying several different materials, to match the lighting designed by Dir. of Photography David Wolski.

One can interpret “additional layer on top of practical photography” to mean what is seen on film does not actually physically exist; some of the lamps features — the vein elements — were finished as post-production VFX.